# How to configure Zipkin to use MS SQLServer database?

Tags: sql-server, zipkin

On the official Zipkin repository [README](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/tree/master/zipkin-server) I see how to configure Zipkin with either Cassandra, MySql or Elastic Search. However in my current job, we'd like to make use of Zipkin, but we are limited to Microsoft SQL Server as the only supported database.

AFAIK Zipkin works with MySql via standard JDBC driver, therefore I think it would be possible to make it work with SqlServer as well. Am I right? If so, how can I configure it to work over it?

Comment: There must be some config somewhere where you specify a JDBC connection string. You change that string to point at your SQL Server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url

Comment: I'm afraid this is not the case. It looks like MySQL connection string [is build from provided config values](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/tree/master/zipkin-server#mysql-storage), not set up front.

Comment: Now that I reread your question.... it's clearly not supported. MySQL dialect is different to T-SQL so someone has to actually write a sql server module. It won't just drop in.